# Google Analytics: Enabled 'Track site search results' , where do I see list with search queries

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I enabled 'Track site search results' on Google Analytics and put also the queryparameter. Now my question is, where can I simply look at the list that is gathered with all the searches that are done by users?

Searched a lot but nothing found...

Thanks

Comment: FYI, so you're aware, this is probably more of a question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com Stack Overflow is for programming questions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report you look for is under Content -> Site Search -> Search terms.

You might also find [this tutorial](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/internal_site_search_v15_ad/) helpful.